# Mercurial Loss of Code

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I work in Mercurial and I recently pushed a few changesets to a repository. Another person merged and pushed their stuff.

At this point one of my files had edits that were lost within the merge process. I back tracked the files to see where the removal of the code occured but I can't find any case where the lines were explicitly removed.

Does anyone know what could have happened here? I looked and the 1 changeset above mine doesn't include the code. It was a hg merging changeset.

Comment: During manual merge merger can remove and non-conflicted part of code. hg diff will help you. Use two -r or -c <mergeset> -r <your parent>

Comment: Can you find a revision where those edits existed? or do you mean you had edits in your working copy when the merge was done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No line of code that's been committed is **ever** lost.

A merge is just a commit with two parents -- the merger can include or remove any code from either parent.

The tricky part is that the normal commands one uses to see where code might have been removed (`hg log -p` for example) compare a changeset with its **left** parent, so you'll only see additions and removals relative to that parent.

If, for example, history looks like this:

```
[A]--[B]--[D]
   \     /
    -[C]-
```

(where A is the parent of both B and C, and D has two parents B and C)

If you change was added in B, but D's *left* parent is C and D's *right* parent is B, then when you run `hg log -p` to see patches you're seeing:

- A as compared to nothing
- B as compared to A <-- shows the change you added
- C as compared to A
- D as compared to C

None of those will show the removal of your change.  To see that you need D as compared to B, which you'd get with:

```
hg diff -r B -r D
```

So the person that merged tossed your code, and you can dig around a bit for proof.

Comment: should that not be `hg diff -r B -r D`?